# SecurePay session error on payment page after clicking continue button. ( Chrome Issue )

Tags: google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, securepay

We are using SecurePay hosted payment gateway. 
The card details / payment page opens up, but after click on the continue button on card details page session error notification is displayed.

Please refer image below for detail.

[image]

Note - This issue is occurring in Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit). Chrome incognito / Firefox browser it is working fine.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome incognito?  I assume you've already cleared your browser cache and cookies etc?

Comment: Yeah we had clear cache and cookies.